# WordPress "Load more" plugin on client side without AJAX calls or WordPress queries

Tags: wordpress

I have more than 100 `li` elements on a page.  I want to display first 5 `li` elements and a "Load more" button.  When I clicked on "Load more" button it displays the next five records and the  "Load more" button disables when there is no more `li` records available on the page.  I don't want to use any ajax call and no WordPress query is needed.

```
<ul class="paging-example">
    foreach ($resultset as $idx => $row)
    {
        if($row->Type == '1')
        {
            echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $row->Title . "</a></li>";
        }

    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Create a js variable with a json array. You can use js to load more elements etc.

Comment: +1 with @David. Try wp_localize_script to create js object on your page. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well sticking to how you said you want to do it, having 100 list items but only showing the first five, and then showing more when clicking "Load More":

First off in your php:

```
echo '<ul class="paging-example">';
$counter = 0;
    foreach ($resultset as $idx => $row)
    {
        if( $row->Type == '1' )
        {
            echo "<li style='" . ( $counter >= 5 ? 'display: none;' : '' ) . "'><a href='#'>" . $row->Title . "</a></li>";
            $counter++;
        }

    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Next for your javascript, I'm assuming jQuery is fine since you are working with Wordpress?  I'm also going to assume the "load more" button has a class of "load_more".

```
(function($){
    $('body').on('click','.load_more',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.paging-example li:hidden:lt(5)').slideDown();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I did a slideDown because I like to have some sort of animation, you could optionally do them item by item, or just display them all at once by using .show() instead.

I used the $('body').on() method also just in case the load more button gets added in dynamically or something.

So to explain though, in the php I simply had it add the display: none for all the elements after the fifth one.

Then the jquery simply selects the first five invisible elements and shows them.

You could also do a for loop and display the first five elements that way, but I went for the simplest way I could think of.

If you need to include jquery you could add:

to your file, but it is WordPress so I'd recommend using wp_enqueue_script, something like
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
in the appropriate hook.

I hope that helps, I can give you a raw javascript way also if you prefer avoiding jQuery, it is just a bit longer.

My full test (outside of WordPress, and with nothing else on the page really) looked like this to make sure I wasn't giving you broken code:

```
<?php
echo '<ul class="paging-example">';
for( $x = 0; $x < 100; $x++ )
{
    echo '<li style="' . ( $x >= 5 ? 'display: none;' : '' ) . '">stuff</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
<button class="load_more">Load More</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $('body').on('click','.load_more',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.paging-example li:hidden:lt(5)').slideDown();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```